# Flutter - Detect enabled accessibilities

Tags: android, ios, flutter, accessibility

is there any way to detect if and when users enable accessibilities on their devices?
in other ways, when for instance a user use a device's accessibility and force to zoom Apps I want to be able to detect that, either with Flutter itself or through a plugin/package ?

Answer (score 1):

```
MediaQuery.accessibleNavigationOf(context);
```

returns `true` if the screen reader is on